# SQL for showing row data in columns

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my sql (in mysql table)

```
select * from(SELECT sample_register.usin,    
                     DATE_FORMAT(sample_register.doc,'%d-%m-%Y') as doc1,    
                     sample_register.location,    
                     sample_register.description,    
                     sample_register.type,    
                     sample_allocation.gamma,    
                     gamma_results.act,    
                     gamma_results.act_sd,    
                     gamma_results.mdl,    
                     gamma_results.bdl,    
                     DATE_FORMAT(count_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as count_dt    
               FROM sample_register    
               LEFT JOIN sample_allocation    
               ON sample_register.usin=sample_allocation.usin    
               LEFT JOIN gamma_results    
               ON gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin    
               AND gamma_results.istp='Cs137'    
               WHERE mid(sample_register.usin,3,1)='F'    
               AND sample_register.doc BETWEEN '2015-01-01'    
                                       AND '2015-03-31'    
                                       AND sample_register.category='ter'    
                                       AND sample_allocation.gamma='Y'    
               ORDER BY mid(sample_register.usin,3,1),    
                        sample_register.doc,    
                        sample_register.usin) AS a    
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT sample_register.usin,    
                                 gamma_results.act,    
                                 gamma_results.act_sd,    
                                 gamma_results.mdl,    
                                 gamma_results.bdl    
                          FROM sample_register    
                          LEFT JOIN gamma_results    
                          ON gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin    
                          AND gamma_results.istp='k40'    
                          WHERE mid(sample_register.usin,3,1)='F'    
                          AND sample_register.doc    
                          BETWEEN '2015-01-01'    
                          AND '2015-03-31'    
                          AND (sample_register.category='ter')    
                          ORDER BY mid(sample_register.usin,3,1),    
                                   sample_register.doc,    
                                   sample_register.usin) AS b    
               ON a.usin=b.usin
```

There are 4 records in the gamma_results table. two records each for 10/04/2015 and 18/04/2015.

```
USIN        istp     act     count_dt
-----------------------------------------
15FML002    Cs137   0.00769  10/04/15
15FML002    K40     0        10/04/15
15FML002    Cs137   0.00608  18/04/15
15FML002    K40     12.117   18/04/15
```

Query output data in the following form  (some fields I deleted for convenience)

```
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    12.117
15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    12.117
```

But I want to get output in two records. That is like this

```
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    12.117
```

How can I reframe (join or union) the query to get output like this?
/// edited on 30/04/2015

I am unable to create an sqlfiddle because of some proplem in their site. Here is the DDL and DML for the two tables sample_register and gamma results. The sample_allocation table can be ignored at this juncture.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample_register` (
  `usin` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `sample_id` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `doc` date NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fwt` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This filed contains either fwt in gms or volume in ltr for milk or volume of air for particulate',
  `dwt` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ashwt` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_dt` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'This is for particulate sample filter removal date',
  `wc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `oc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ac` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usin`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `sample_register` VALUES ('15FML002', 'NIL', '2015-04-09', 'MALLAPUR', 'ter', 'MILK', 'milk', '2000.00', null, null, '1604015', null, null, null, null, null, null);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `gamma_results`;
CREATE TABLE `gamma_results` (
  `usin` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sysid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `count_time` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vol` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `energy` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `istp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bkg` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eff` decimal(10,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sigma` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ncps` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sd` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mdl` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `act` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `act_sd` decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bdl` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `entered_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `count_dt` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `gamma_results` VALUES ('15FML002', 'HPGE2', '25000', 'nb', '1000.00', '364.48', 'I131', '0.01000', '3.400', '0.00190', '-0.01000', '0.00041', '0.06882', null, '0.00000', 'Y', '2015-04-13 10:24:11', '1619381', '2015-04-10');
INSERT INTO `gamma_results` VALUES ('15FML002', 'HPGE2', '25000', 'nb', '1000.00', '661.66', 'Cs137', '0.00020', '2.060', '0.00027', '-0.00020', '0.00006', '0.00769', null, '0.00000', 'Y', '2015-04-13 10:24:57', '1619381', '2015-04-10');
INSERT INTO `gamma_results` VALUES ('15FML002', 'HPGE2', '25000', 'nb', '1000.00', '1460.73', 'K40', '0.00500', '0.911', '0.00134', '-0.00450', '0.00032', '1.37855', null, '0.00000', 'Y', '2015-04-13 10:25:37', '1619381', '2015-04-10');
INSERT INTO `gamma_results` VALUES ('15FML002', 'HPGE2', '15000', 'nb50', '2000.00', '661.66', 'Cs137', '0.00020', '3.380', '0.00035', '-0.00020', '0.00006', '0.00608', null, '0.00000', 'Y', '2015-04-20 10:21:48', '1619381', '2015-04-18');
INSERT INTO `gamma_results` VALUES ('15FML002', 'HPGE2', '15000', 'nb50', '2000.00', '1460.73', 'K40', '0.00500', '1.550', '0.00173', '0.04008', '0.00176', '0.52302', '12.11700', '0.53200', 'N', '2015-04-20 10:23:00', '1619381', '2015-04-18');
```

Comment: What is the criteria to reduce that dataset? It looks like there are common values to group into pairs other than the last column, where you're choosing `00` the first time and `12.117` the second time?

Comment: For each USINs there are two different values for istp  on a single count_dt. Hence on each count date there will be two records for a USIN with one for istp='k40' and another for istp=cs137. Since USIN and count date are common , I want to display it in a single row. Then if there are more than one (say' n') count dates for a USIN then there would be nx2 records. But I need only n rows.

Comment: Can you provide DDL and insert data so that I can try?

Answer (score 8):

I have seen output like this before.

It is caused by a tiny error in the joining. If I remember correctly I solved this by nesting some of my joins as sub queries so I was adding each table to an existing table along a join. I probably over egged the mix but it did work nicely. (UPDATE: Yeah, I see now that is exactly what you are doing).

At some point in that mix the join has not been unique or the way you have arranged it has not been unique and so SQL has given you all the combinations it could come up with.

(Assuming, of course, that it is not just a missing `GROUP BY` that is upsetting things. That's the other source of problems like this.)

I will have a careful look through your SQL and see if I can spot the problem but a little trial and error would be much, much faster.

**UPDATE 1:** This is either a really impressive hack or an error and I cannot fathom which.

```
LEFT JOIN gamma_results    
ON gamma_results.usin = sample_register.usin    
AND gamma_results.istp='Cs137'
```

I have never seen a conditional as part of a join. I could not tell you if this would even work but my gut reaction is to want to put this in the `WHERE` clause. Feel free to take me to school on this as you seem to know what you are doing and I do not have hands on to the actual project (nor do I know everything).

**Update 2:** Given that your hard coded join must be close to working my feeling is that I would want a GROUP by in the nested SELECT as you are using aggregate functions (`count`).

I recall once making a quite complex query that when you get right down to it was effectively saying "for each table_a add table_b". Honestly make friends with `GROUP BY` and if that does not solve your problem then I am a small inoffensive monkey.

Comment: Re: the conditional as part of a `JOIN`... In `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, or (for other SQL implementations) `OUTER`, putting a conditional in the join can be very useful. It has a very different meaning than if it were outside of the conditional. In fact, it would render one of those `JOIN`s to be an effective `INNER JOIN` because it would require a value in that column for the condition to have the chance of being met. If you ever take a look at an `OUTER JOIN` you will immediately understand the benefits.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you should provide same data and sqlfiddle if you need help with query for some specific dataset.

Since I have no data for the fiddle here is my guess:

```
SELECT sample_register.usin,    
     DATE_FORMAT(sample_register.doc,'%d-%m-%Y') as doc1,    
     sample_register.location,    
     sample_register.description,    
     sample_register.type,    
     sample_allocation.gamma,    
     gr.act,    
     gr.act_sd,    
     gr.mdl,    
     gr.bdl,    
     gr.count_dt,
     grK40.act  
FROM sample_register    
INNER JOIN sample_allocation    
ON sample_register.usin=sample_allocation.usin
   AND sample_allocation.gamma='Y'
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
       usin,
    act,    
    act_sd,    
    mdl,    
    bdl,
    count_dt,
    DATE_FORMAT(count_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as count_dt_formatted    
   FROM gamma_results    
   WHERE istp='Cs137'
) gr
ON gr.usin = sample_register.usin
LEFT JOIN gamma_results grK40   
 ON grK40.usin = gr.usin
    AND grK40.istp='k40'
    AND grK40.count_dt = gr.count_dt
WHERE mid(sample_register.usin,3,1)='F'    
AND sample_register.doc BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-03-31'    
   AND sample_register.category='ter'    
ORDER BY mid(sample_register.usin,3,1),    
    sample_register.doc,    
    sample_register.usin
```

But it is just a guess, because it looks very weir to me.

You wrote:

*There are 4 records in the gamma_results table. two records each for 10/04/2015 and 18/04/2015.: `USIN`,`istp`,`act`,`count_dt`* but in your query you use `act,act_sd,mdl,bdl,DATE_FORMAT(count_dt,'%d-%m-%Y') as count_dt` so we can assume that you have some other columns there like:  `act_sd,mdl,bdl`.

Underneath you wrote: *Query output data in the following form (some fields I deleted for convenience)*

```
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    12.117
```

Even if some field deleted, what fields are here?

Logically it is: `usin,act`, **UNKNOWN**,`count_dt`,**UNKNOWN** (equal to `act` when `istp='K40'`). but it is impossible, because you haven't such field in your query request. It seems to me that provided output  was get as result of some other query, not that one you show us.

But so far, here is my guess. You are welcome if any questions.

Comment: Thankyou for replying. the fields in the output data are (1)usin, (2) act where istp=cs137, (3)the field showing value 'Y' can be ignored as it is a flag. (4) count_dt, (5) act where istp=k40.

Comment: and? that is exactly what my query is doing?

Answer (score 3):

Every table you write should have a `PRIMARY KEY`. This is a vitally important concept in relational databases. While you have a `PRIMARY KEY` in `sample_register`, you do not have one in `gamma_results`.

## If you have a primary key, this is a walk in the park (relatively speaking)

Assuming you have the following rows:

```
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    12.117
15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    00
15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    12.117
```

And assuming that these are actually duplicates of distinct rows in your database, assigning primary keys will create a new column which will make your data look like this:

```
1          15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    00
1          15FML002            0.00769 Y   10/04/15    12.117
2          15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    00
2          15FML002            0.00608 Y   18/04/15    12.117
```

This is a bit of an oversimplification for your example, considering that within an explanation inside of your question, you stated that

> For each USINs there are two different values for istp on a single count_dt. Hence on each count date there will be two records for a USIN with one for istp='k40' and another for istp=cs137. Since USIN and count date are common , I want to display it in a single row. Then if there are more than one (say' n') count dates for a USIN then there would be nx2 records. But I need only n rows.

I get that you understand how this data fits together, but your SQL queries will become cleaner and neater if you are able to tell the SQL database how the data fits together in the language it understands.

To understand where your Primary Key goes will help you to better logically understand your table structure. If you can't assign a Primary Key, that means the table probably needs to be split into chunks. This one could certainly benefit from a little normalization.

Clearly you have a 1:n relationship on `USIN` which is well represented here, but you also have a 1:2 relationship on `istp`. This is not reflected in a different table, but instead all in the same table, which means that combinations of `USIN` and `count_dt` are repeated twice throughout the entire table when they are exactly the same.

I am not suggesting that you can't make this query work. All you need to do is stick a `GROUP BY` at the bottom. However, with no indexes to speak of your table is going to be incredibly slow. Even with indexes it's going to be slower than it needs to be! Importantly, without a `PRIMARY KEY` your SQL database is going to be doing more work than it needs to by a long shot.

## The ideal way

If you split your tables into two, providing a new `PRIMARY KEY` for each `USIN`/`count_dt` pair, then create another table that settles your `istp='k40'` and `istp=cs137` requirements, you will only have to write one extra line of queries in your already long query, and it will probably more often than not save you a lot of time querying.

Instead of `SELECT * FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.USIN=tableB.USIN...` you would write:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB on tableA.USIN=tableB.USIN
LEFT JOIN tableX on tableB.id = tableX.tableB_id
....
```

You should end up with the same dataset. If you just want the unique values, all you need to do is get rid of the second `JOIN`.

## If you cannot change your table structure

If for whatever reason you cannot change your table structure, then your alternative would be to create a composite primary key, consisting of `USIN`, `count_dt` and `istp`, as these should be unique and should only show up in a specific combination once in the table. This can quickly balloon out, but should give you the general gist.

To create distinct values using this method, you should have a compound index on `USIN` and `count_dt`, and then use `GROUP BY USIN, count_dt`.

Comment: You have given a wonderful explanation. I cannot split table because there may be more values for istp, though I am preferring here only two. If I split table for each istp there will be a dozen tables. I can add a primary key to gamma_results, but I am little confused how it will help to reduce the tuples

Comment: It's ok to have a lot of tables if they serve different purposes. That being said, a primary key on a table will not reduce tuples, but it will make it much easier and faster to group those values leaving you with distinct columns anyway. The more you focus on database structure, the easier it is to harness SQLs built in awesome power.

Answer (score 0):

@masoondreamz, I have created a fiddle for a possible solution. It is - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bcae/27/0

The essential element of the solution was I grouped by the date in column Count_DT and have added it to the joint condition for the subqueries. I did trim the number of columns to the list you had showed in the sample result.